# unable to get the BigCommerce orders by descending using API v2

Tags: api, bigcommerce

We are trying to get the orders from BigCommerce using API V2. WE have applied the filter but its not working

$filter = array('min_date_created' => 'Tue, 14 JAN 2019 00:00:00 +0000');

How can we get the orders by descending order?

Comment: Please elaborate more on how it is not working

Comment: Used the below code https://api.bigcommerce.com/stores/9lhh7mag2z/v2/orders?date_created:asc&max_date_created=2019-01-15"   getting the following error [status] => 400
            [message] => The field 'date_created:asc' is not supported by this resource.
        )

Answer (score 0):

To sort the orders by ascending use: `https://api.bigcommerce.com/stores/{store_hash}/v2/orders?sort=date_created:asc`

Dates should be in RFC-2822 or ISO-8601 date format. 
To sort by `asc` and `max_date_created` use:

`https://api.bigcommerce.com/stores/{store_hash}/v2/orders?sort=date_created:asc&max_date_created=2018-01-11`

You can review the filters available here: [Orders API](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-reference/orders/orders-api/orders/getorders)

Comment: $BC_Client_Id='izm7rsef6y4pbuobe5vyafq8omxvfec';
$BC_API_Key='4txkqofaco1m5a36wm7mj6bz5tve1me';
$requestUrl = "https://api.bigcommerce.com/stores/9lhh7mag2z/v2/orders?date_created:asc&max_date_created=2019-01-15";
            

Getting the following error [status] => 400
            [message] => The field 'date_created:asc' is not supported by this resource.

Comment: Above solution is not working with the URL https://api.bigcommerce.com/stores/9lhh7mag2z/v2/orders?date_created:asc&max_date_created=2019-01-15" Getting the following error [status] => 400
            [message] => The field 'date_created:asc' is not supported by this resource.

Comment: Can you please try the request in a api client such as Postman. I was able to return results using that. We should be sure the url works and it is not something with the code.

Comment: @sandipdalvi Please be sure to remove your API keys from this post or revoke access to avoid compromising security on your store

Comment: We have tried in Postman but still facing same issue. Could you please try at your end with the URL I have given?

Comment: You are missing the sort keyword.https://api.bigcommerce.com/stores/{store_hash}/v2/orders?sort=date_created:asc&max_date_created=2018-01-1

Comment: https://api.bigcommerce.com/stores/9lhh7mag2z/v2/orders?sort=date_created:asc&max_date_created=2019-01-17

Comment: https://api.bigcommerce.com/stores/9lhh7mag2z/v2/orders?sort=date_created:asc&max_date_created=2019-01-17 We are still getting the all orders from store. The filter is not yet applied. We only want the orders which are created on 2019-01-17

Comment: @T.J. any comment on above questions?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
https://api.bigcommerce.com/stores/{{store_hash}}/v2/orders?min_date_created={{min_date_created}}&sort=date_created:desc
```

Where {{store_hash}} is the BigCommerce Store Hash and {{min_date_created}} is the date formatted like 2017-01-10T06:54:07Z.

This will present the orders created after the date variable and sorted in descending order (most recent first).